# Close form program when close button is disabled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to close a application when a button is pressed but I wanted to disable the close button (X button upper right).

I disabled the close button with this code:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

But now when I try to close the program with this code it wont work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Is there a way to close this program when the button is clicked?

Comment: This is a pretty cruel user experience.  Don't disable the close button; let them use it if they want to close the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event handler, check the [CloseReason property of the FormClosingEventArgs:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This allows you to behave differently depending on [how the close was initiated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so in the case of Application Exit (or Windows Shutdown) you can allow the form to close.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall
     && e.CloseReason != CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
     {
          e.Cancel = true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're cancelling ALWAYS the closign of the form, so that's why it doesn't works.

Try this:

```
bool blockClosing = true;

protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = blockClosing;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    blockClosing = false;
    Application.Exit();
}
```

In this way, when you press your button it will allow tha pp to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

`FormClosingEventArgs` has a `Reason` member that tells you what exactly is trying to close your form. Simply allow `ApplicationExitCall` through without canceling it.